# Java Counter not counting

Tags: java, counter, increment

I am stuck on a problem in having my counter increment.  I'm not sure what I am doing wrong though. Sorry if this is a beginner mistake, but I have not found a solution where I understand or helps yet.

```
  public static int duplicates(String[] text, int numWords){
            int currentCount = 1;
            for (int i=0; i<numWords-1; i++){
                for (int j=i+1; j<numWords; j++){
                    if (text[i] == text[j]){
                        currentCount++;

                    }
                }   
            }

            return currentCount;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

To compare objects in java use .equals() method instead of "==" operator

`if (text[i] == text[j])` need to change to `if (text[i].equals(text[j]))`

if you want to ignore the case use `.equalsIgnoreCase()` instead of `.equals()`

Answer (score 0):

```
if (text[i] == text[j])
```

Your mistake is in the line above.

In Java you should not use the `==` operator to compare Strings. That will check if the 2 strings are the same object (identity comparison), but you want to check whether they have the same content (value comparison).

You need to use `text[i].equals(text[j])` instead.

If your method is supposed to handle `null` values in the array (i.e. `text[i]` can be null) then you will need to check for null before you call `equals`.

Answer (score 0):

replace `if (text[i] == text[j]){` to `if (text[i].equals(text[j])){`

use this way

```
public static int duplicates(String[] text, int numWords){
            int currentCount = 1;
            for (int i=0; i<numWords-1; i++){
                for (int j=i+1; j<numWords; j++){
                    if (text[i].equals(text[j])){
                        currentCount++;

                    }
                }   
            }

            return currentCount;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are comparing string values, use the equals method.

```
if (text[i].equals(text[j])) {
```